# How to insert fields of the Document Information Panel inside the body of DOTX document?

Tags: 2010, development, sharepoint-enterprise, word

In a DOTX template document, how can I **insert a placeholder for the fields in the Document Information Panel?**

I'm only being able to insert document properties, via the Quick Parts button.

And, if inserting DIP fields in the body of the document is not possible, what is the usage of DIP? How is it commonly used?

Comment: What's wrong with inserting quick parts into the document?

Comment: @PerJakobsen: Nothing, but not all fields in my Document Information Panel appear as a selectable document property. Also, as DIP is filled automatically, I'd like to fill the the body of the document with that info.